# Control collision in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, collision-detection

i have an app here and i let the user drag link labels around on the form, but i need to be able to do stuff when the linklabel they are dragging around touches another control on the form. can anybody please point me in the right direction? or offer any suggestions/advice?

thanks lots
jase

Answer (score 4):

You could possibly use [Rectangle.IntersectsWith](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle.intersectswith.aspx) on the `Bounds` of the controls to detect collision.